# Are my instantiations of Axiom 5 (Mendelson) correct?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, predicate-logic, axioms, hilbert-calculus

I'm reading "Introduction to mathematical logic" from Mendelson. I'm in chapter 2 "First-order logic and Model theory".I am interested in learning the axiomatic method without using the deduction theorem, but I'm having a hard time understanding how the axioms of first order logic are instantiated correctly. In this case I have some quiestions about Axiom 5: $(∀x_i
)(B ⇒ C) ⇒ (B ⇒ (∀x_i
)C)$ restriction: if $B$ contains no free occurrences of $x_i$
.

1. First instantiation: $(∀x)((∀x)B ⇒ C) ⇒ ((∀x)B ⇒ (∀x)C)$
2. Second instantiation: $(∀x)(∀y)((∀y)B ⇒ C) ⇒ ((∀y)B ⇒ (∀x)C)$

This is my thought process:

In the first instantiation I replace $B$ with $(∀x)B$, I think it is a correct instantiation because all occurrences of $x$ in $B$ are not free but the antecedent $(∀x)((∀x)B ⇒ C)$ worries me because I don't know if I'm allowed to do that.

In the second instantiation I replace $B$ with $(∀y)B$. I think it is a wrong instantiation because $B$ can be a formula like $Px ⇒ Qy$ so this way $Px$ is free in $B$ (since the quantifier is ∀y) and this violates the restriction of the axiom.

So my question is : Are my instantiations and thought process correct?

Also: Can you give more examples of correct instantiations of Axiom 5?

Comment: 1st one is correct. 2nd one the first quantifier to "move is $(\forall y)$ and $y$ is not free in $(\forall y) B$. Thus, the result will be like the previous one: $((∀y)B ⇒ (∀y)C)$

Comment: Having said that, if $x$ is not free in $C$, it is not free in $(\forall y)C$ either, and thus the last one is equiv to $(\forall x)C$

Comment: Thank you for the answer Mauro¡. What do you mean by "the first quantifier to move is ∀y" . Also: I realise that I worte one more quantifier than what I had in mind. I worte (∀x)(∀y) ((∀y)B ⇒ C) ⇒ ((∀yB ⇒ ∀xC) insted of (∀x) ((∀y)B ⇒ C) ⇒ ((∀yB ⇒ ∀xC). Does this change things? Should I edit it? Thank you for your time¡.